# Error trying to connect to FedEx Ship Service API when using PHP

Tags: php, web-services, fedex

I had decided to integrate FedEx Shipping Service into one of my online apps.
I downloaded a sample PHP code from the FedEX developer center. But when I tried to work with the ShipGroundDomestic.php5 I am getting error. I modified the file according to my specifications & plugged in the credentials. But I am unable to make it work. I am getting following error,

Fault
Code:HTTP
String:Could not connect to host

I have made sure that there are no file path issues & other related issues. But I am constantly getting this error. I was wondering if any of you guys have worked with this & would know how to resolve this. I tried contacting the FedEx guys but its unhelpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you done a packet capture to see if you are generating/sending packets or if it fails before that.  If it fails to generate packets then check to make sure the app is resolving the URL properly.

Comment: Do you mean the components for constructing the request like MeterNumber, AccountNumber etc? Then yeah they are being initialized properly. The point of failure is 
$response = $client->processShipment($request);  // FedEx web service invocation

Comment: Nope, I mean capture on the network device to see if you're actually generating requests, or if it is failing before that.

Comment: This might be a naive request. But this is my first time with actually implementing a web service. Can you please tell me how to exactly capture on the network device? I have placed the request object inside a try/catch block & the flow always goes to the catch block. & prints the aforementioned Fault Code.

Comment: I also checked whether SOAP is enabled on my PHP BOX & it is.

Comment: Download and install wireshark : http://www.wireshark.org/download.html  This program attaches to your network device and will show all traffic inbound and outbound.

If you are running a version of linux on the server you can use a commandline version called tcpump.  eg) tcpdump -i any dst port 80 or dst port 443

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I found out that the web server was firewalled to outside internal network. So had my networks guy configure fix this. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

This problems occurs when your are using Proxy Server.

Comment: This isn't so much an answer to the problem, as more a diagnosis of the problem. Could you expand the answer to explain how to fix or work around the issue?